# str_replace() not working with while loop with variable for search argument

Tags: php, str-replace

```php
$query1 = mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT words FROM banlist ORDER BY words") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $fix = (string)$row['words'];                   
    $title = str_replace($fix, "-", $title);
}

echo $title;
```

`var_dump($row)`'s output:

```
array(1) {
    ["words"]=> string(5) "hello "
}
array(1) {
    ["words"]=> string(5) "you "
}
```

It doesn't replace any string in the title But if I put the values directly like `"hello"` in the place of `$fix` then it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($row)` in a mean `while`?

Comment: this is what output of var_dump($row) inside the while
`array(1) { ["words"]=> string(5) "hello" } array(1) { ["words"]=> string(5) "you " }`

Comment: the `$title` inside `str_replace` isn't defined.

Comment: And what `var_dump($title)` is inside the loop?

Comment: it is defined as `$title = $_POST['title']` in the beginning of the page.

Comment: so you want to replace hello and you with - in title. what is initial title and do you get in the end

Comment: `var_dump($title)` gives the `string(25) "this is a hello world page for you"`

Comment: @JoshKisb Yes Indeed. If i use `$fix` then it gives the same output as the `$title` but if i use a string directly like `"hello"` then it does replaces.

Comment: What is the value of $row['words'] when you dump that in the loop?

Comment: @SimonR it does fetches the values from the table.

Comment: Yes I realise that but what values e.g. is it returning a string, and if it is, is the value one already in your title?

Comment: @SimonR This is the ouput `string(5) "hello " string(5) "you "` I think its the space coming after every value how can i include data from a file to mysql by trimming it

Comment: just use trim($row['words']) to eliminate that issue.

Comment: @SimonR Thankyou very much that worked fine.

Comment: No worries! Glad it worked.

Comment: Small observation: You actually print `mysql_error()` instead of `mysqli_error()`;

Comment: @GerritLuimstra Actually it worked by removing the space from the values but thankyou for telling me this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through some troubleshooting with you, we ascertained that it was the space coming from the database field. To correct the issue code should be changed to

```
$query1 = mysqli_query($cone,"SELECT words FROM banlist ORDER BY words") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $fix = trim($row['words']);                   
    $title = str_replace($fix, "-", $title);
}

echo $title;
```

Ideally strings should be trimmed as they get inserted to the database to prevent this issue.